# Why is CDN Linking to ReactJS Not Working

Tags: reactjs

Why does this not work? I checked the React docs and the CDN links seem to be all right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
  <script>
    const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>;
    ReactDOM.render(element, document.querySelector("body"));
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: `const element = <h1>Hello, world</h1>` is not valid `JavaScript`, you need a transpiler, such as `Babel`, to turn your `JSX` code into something that browsers can understand.

Comment: See https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#optional-try-react-with-jsx for how to add Babel and tell it that script needs processing. Please note that "not working" isn't a very helpful description of the problem.

Comment: Oh. Right. Thanks!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, this code wasn't working, and that's what I wrote.

Comment: And what made you think it's not working? What did you see on the page? What did it say in the console? What had you *expected*? See [mre].

Comment: I saw nothing one the page, which is what made me think it was not working. It said `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` on the console. And I expected the words `Hello, world` to be displayed on the screen. I am a beginner to React and JSX, so I wouldn't know! (I began learning react around 20 minutes ago)

Comment: So put that information _in the question_, don't make people guess for themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use JSX, you need a transpiler such as Babel because JSX support is not built in to browsers.

You can use the Babel CDN:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there no way we can use JSX with only React?

Comment: @Adith do you mean without loading additional packages like Babel from a CDN? No, if you only want to load React use the createElement syntax.

Comment: All right! Thanks! Anyway, I'll be allowed to accept your answer in `2 minutes`

Comment: @Adith you can use the CDNs to try React and JSX out, but for a production app I would recommend using npm and create-react-app, which handles the babel part and is a better workflow. https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Comment: All right! I didn't use that because last time I tried it took around half an hour to finish. (I guess that is because I have a very slow computer). But I'm getting an M1 Mac tomorrow, so I guess problem solved!